# Is possible to use JclDebug to get the parameters values from the method that raised the exception?

Tags: delphi, exception

I use the function 'JclGetExceptStackList' to log the call stack of the raised exceptions.

I wish, that if possible to also log the parameters value from the method that raised the exception.

I dont know if is possible to do that with JclDebug, or that exists any other way to do that.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this SO question about logging practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728879/what-do-you-log-in-your-desktop-applications-to-improve-stability/6729093#6729093).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's not possible to do it with JclDebug, and while doing it by hand might be a lot of work, you might find that any logging tool, including Log4D, or CodeSite or even outputdebugString, could do it with less work. It will in fact be inserting code to log your parameter calls, in any place where you choose to insert such logging.   It can also insert a special marker when an exception is raised, allowing you to reconstruct the exact scenario that lead to your crash.

But since CodeSite doesn't do it only when an exception is going to happen (how would it?) this isn't exactly what you wanted.  I do find however, that a reasonable trace log, combined with the jcl stack traceback (or madeexcept or eurekalog) is more than enough and that if I really need to know all the parameter values involved in a call, I should go back and add more trace messages.

Comment: +1 because answer specifies that parameters should be part of the logged material.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible in general because parameters are typically passed in registers. which are overwritten each time a procedure call is made.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't know that do this is not possible.

Comment: It would probably be possible in Java and C# because they have deeper runtime reflection capabilities, but Delphi prioritizes runtime performance over high-level inspection at runtime.