# Accessing procedure arguments without their name

Tags: delphi, arguments, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Not even sure if this is possible, but thought I would ask the hive mind.

In Delphi, I know it is possible to loop through the component array of a form, accessing components 'indirectly' if you do not know their name (for instance, components that are created at run-time).

Is this same principle possible for the arguments of a procedure/function?

Basically, I have to refactor a lot of code to log values passed to procedures, and I am trying to find a way to write something generic that can be copied/pasted into the method and not have to be updated if the argument list changes.

For example, something along these lines:

```
procedure SomeProcedure(a, b, c:String; i, j, k:Integer);
var
     loopCounter:integer;
begin
     for loopCounter:=low(METHOD_ARGUMENTS???) to high(METHOD_ARGUMENTS???) do
     begin
          log.add(METHOD_ARGUMENTS[loopCounter].name, METHOD_ARGUMENTS[loopCounter].value);
     end;//for
end;//SomeProcedure
```

where `METHOD_ARGUMENTS` is the 'object' being accessed with the list of arguments passed in.

Like I say, not even sure if this is a thing - but it would definitely make life easier moving forward.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no compiler macro or anything to access _method argument number five_ or anything like that. It also looks like the wrong approach to me. If you want to log arguments that got passed into methods you can do that by RTTI, for example with a `TVirtualMethodInterceptor`. Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6835989/2298252

Comment: Some parts of the Delphi RTL mimic C's variable argument lists by using a single parameter of type `array of const` which boils down to `array of TVarRec`. The well-known `String.Format(..)` is an example for this.

Comment: @Günther the Beautiful - thanks for the advice!  I use RTTI when working with types (parsing properties/fields to specific formats etc), and that is what got me thinking if it were possible to 'access procedure argument number five' - didn't think so, and thanks for confirming!