# Tracking memory usage in Delphi application

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am developing a application with Delphi 7 (with FastMM4) my goal is to use as less memory as possible. Is it possible to determine what is using the memory in my application?

Right now the application needs the following memory:

- FastMM: 100kb (messured with https://stackoverflow.com/a/5471218/1124225)
- Workingset: 10MB
- Private Workingset: 2MB

So what I allocate by myself needs about 100KB, but the amount of physical memory is much more.

Is it possible to find out what is occupying the additional memory? (I tried the VCL Class Profiler from AQTime Version 3, but the sum of all objects was a lot less)

Comment: Have you seen the FastMM's [`Usage Tracker`](http://sourceforge.net/p/fastmm/code/HEAD/tree/Demos/Usage%20Tracker/) ?

Comment: Achieving your stated goals will lead to your program performing more poorly than it needs to. Why do you seek poor performance?

Comment: It has to run on a machine with only 32MB of memory (which is already very low for what is running there yet), that's why I need it to use as less memory as possible. Unfortunately upgrading the hardware is not easy in this case

Comment: What OS are you running on? But anyway, my point stands, allocate as little memory as possible, and let the OS do the rest. If you want a program that doesn't use a lot of memory, perhaps Delphi is the wrong choice of tool.

Comment: Are you worried about the `Working Set` value?  If so, don't be.  It's not really a meaningful number (most of that is shared memory anyway).  Otherwise, you are probably using 1MB of that 2MB of private memory for your main thread's stack.  If you want to trim and you know you don't need the stack space you could reduce the max stack size per thread (project options).  How complex is your gui?  Any images, resources, etc?